# Converting standard input to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, stdin

I have the standard input:

```
'Town3, NYC, Town1, Town4, Town5, Town6, Town2
 67, 69, 60, 63, 65, 69, 95'
```

I wonder how can I turn this to pandas data frame such that I get:

```
   Town3  NYC  Town1  Town4  Town5  Town6  Town2
0     67   69     60     63     65     69     95
```

Comment: Your standard input is not a valid string in Python. If this is a multiline strings you need to enclose with triple quotes. s = '''...''' and the @AndrejKesely's answer is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `io.StringIO` + `pd.read_csv`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """Town3, NYC, Town1, Town4, Town5, Town6, Town2
 67, 69, 60, 63, 65, 69, 95"""

df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(s),
    sep=r",\s*",
    engine="python",
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Town3  NYC  Town1  Town4  Town5  Town6  Town2
0     67   69     60     63     65     69     95
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your string into list. Cut it in 2 equals parts. The first part are the columns and the second one are the values:

```
s = 'Town3, NYC, Town1, Town4, Town5, Town6, Town2, 67, 69, 60, 63, 65, 69, 95'
l = s.split(', ')

df = pd.DataFrame([l[len(l)//2:]], columns=l[:len(l)//2])
```

```
>>> df

  Town3 NYC Town1 Town4 Town5 Town6 Town2
0    67  69    60    63    65    69    95
```